# Start a new line while using the Sheets.Range.Formula property

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the Sheets.Range.Formula method to create complex conditional statements within VBA and was wondering if it is possible to break up the line of code so that I can comment on each portion's purpose and also just for better readability. DISCLAIMER: I can only use this method and not the traditional IfThenElse Statement which I know how to continue onto the next line ( _).Below is an example of what I have, a really long and ugly conditional statement:

```
SheetName.Range("B23").Formula = "=IF(AND(SheetName!$E12="",OR(SheetName!$W3="",SheetName!$W3="",SheetName!$W3="")),B$9,IF(AND(SheetName!$W3="",B$9>=B$19,OR(SheetName!$E12="",SheetName!$E12="")),B$9 etc.
```

What I would like to accomplish is to break each line of code up while still continuing the statement. I've tried using the underscore character, however I receive the message (Compile Error, Syntax Error) so I'm thinking that's not the solution.

```
SheetName.Range("B23").Formula = "=IF(AND(SheetName!$E12="",OR(SheetName!$W3="",SheetName!$W3="",SheetName!$W3="")),B$9,
IF(AND(SheetName!$W3="",B$9>=B$19,OR(SheetName!$E12="",SheetName!$E12="")),B$9 --comment
IF(AND(SheetName!$W3="",B$9>=B$19,OR(SheetName!$E12="",SheetName!$E12="")),B$9 --comment
IF(AND(SheetName!$W3="",B$9>=B$19,OR(SheetName!$E12="",SheetName!$E12="")),B$9 --comment
IF(AND(SheetName!$W3="",B$9>=B$19,OR(SheetName!$E12="",SheetName!$E12="")),B$9 etc.
```

As I mentioned, I do not know if it is feasible to accomplish what I need without using a traditional IfThenElse statement structure, however if it is, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to end each line with `" & _` - but still this is not a good way to do it, as you are limited to 25 line continuations. You should find a different solution that serves your needs.

Comment: Hi @braX, is the cap of 25 line continuations for the specific formula or for the entire module etc.?

Comment: for the entire line you are trying to continue - in your example you have 5 lines, so only 20 more are possible, but you have `etc` which means you plan on adding a lot more.

Comment: Hi @braX, understood, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Aslo (for example) `SheetName!$E12=""` should be `SheetName!$E12=""""` If there are double quotes in a string you need to double them up to escape them.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, good catch. While I am aware of that concept, I do appreciate you clearing that up as someone else who might come across this thread might not be aware of it.